# What proxy package to install under Ubuntu/OpenSUSE

Tags: linux, ubuntu, browser, proxy, opensuse

I am looking for a software to isntall under Ubuntu or OpenSUSE so that my server can provide proxy to internal users. The proxy needs to support HTTP and HTTPS. Then, All I need to do is to point to its IP address from my browser proxy configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Squid is the gold standard in open source caching proxies.  I don't know how sane the default config in the Ubuntu/OpenSUSE package is, but it's not too difficult to configure.